# How to automatically align an elevatedbutton to the same height as a container in the same row?

Tags: flutter, layout, row, flutter-textformfield

I want my elevatedbutton to align with same height as another container inside a row. I tried to use expanded but it seems like expanded doesn't do anything to the height with the elevated button.

Here's my code

```
Row(
  children: [
    Container(
      width: width / 2,
      child: TextFormField(
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
            labelText: 'Date picker',
            border: OutlineInputBorder()),
      ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () => (displayDatePicker(context)),
          child: const Text("Pick Date")),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Is there a way to achieve that without specifically setting the height of the elevated button using container or sizedbox?

Comment: is Container Fixed for TextFormFIled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have multiple line, I am using `IntrinsicHeight`.

```dart
IntrinsicHeight(
  child: Row(
    children: [
      SizedBox(
        width: 222,
        child: TextFormField(
          maxLines: 33,
          minLines: 1,
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Date picker', border: OutlineInputBorder()),
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        //to grab width
        child: FractionallySizedBox(
          heightFactor: 1,
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: const Text("Pick Date"),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

---

The default material size for [TextFiled height is 48px](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/42449), you  can set the height on ElevatedButton using style or `SizedBox`.

```dart
Row(
  children: [
    Container(
      width: 222,
      child: TextFormField(
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
            labelText: 'Date picker', border: OutlineInputBorder()),
      ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: ElevatedButton(
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              fixedSize: Size.fromHeight(48)),
          onPressed: () {},
          child: const Text("Pick Date")),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: Well the fixed height works, but if I for example if I add "maxLines: null," into the TextFormField then the height will still be 48 pixels when I enter multiple lines, is there a way to make it change according to the container's height?

Comment: It will be little expensive , check update snippet snippet `IntrinsicHeight`